# How to test if carrierwave file changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I'm trying to test if a image was changed with carrier wave on my code, but I can't find a way to do this. It seems that the object is marked as changed even if the file is invalid, and thus it was not really changed.

Look the following output:

```
(rdb:1) job.translated_xliff
#<XliffUploader:0xcd8b380 ...>
(rdb:1) job.changed?
false # As expected, didn't changed yet
(rdb:1) job.translated_xliff = "foo"
"foo"
(rdb:1) job.changed?
true # Changed? "foo" is not a valid file. Lets see the file again...
(rdb:1) job.translated_xliff
#<XliffUploader:0xcd8b380 ...> # same object ID!
```

How can I check if this object was really changed on my code?

EDIT: I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1174#issuecomment-21793365), but the problem still not solved, yet more information can be found there

Comment: #same object Id because the uploader  object is cache see [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L318) and AFAIK that is currently not possible all you can do is checked the `identifier` and see if its the same or not but I can be wrong as well I'll find it out and let you know abt it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally Carrierwave define(override) the ActiveRecord `getter/setter` on uploader column (`translated_xliff`)

Now every time one call the setter method job.translated_xliff = 'foo' (as mention by `Bensie`)  it uses `ActiveRecord::Dirty` `_will_change!` method to  notify the object it changing

followed by CarrierWave caching the supplied `file`

Here yours scenario

```
    job.translated_xliff
    => uploader 

    job.changed?
    => false

    job.translated_xliff = "foo"

    ## Now your trying to change the object so will_change! notify that 
    ##'translated_xliff' is changing after which Carrierwave try to cache the given 'file'(foo)
```

Now here the problem just before Carriewave start caching the file it perform a basic check like this

```
  new_file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(new_file)
  unless new_file.empty?
     ## Then  do caching 
  end
```

`empty?` is use to determine is supplied value (in your case it `foo`) is a `Path` or `File` and it neither of two in your case  and hence the file is never cache but the object is marked as `changed`

and hence you get this

```
job.changed?
=> true
```

Now as a result  while calling the `job.translated_xliff` method it pull the `file` from the store since the supplied `value` was never cached , you can see it working over  [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L317)

Hence I mention in the comment If you want to achieve something of that kind perhaps you can check against the `identifier` and decide whether it changed

`job.translated_xliff.identifier == "foo"`

Just a suggestion though :)

Hope this help

Comment: It seems I was not smart enough to understand your comment. Thanks for the full explanation.