# How to clearly compare old value with new one?

Tags: ruby

A common piece of code that I already repeated some times, and never liked it, consists in save a value, do an action, and evaluate the value afterwards. Look at the following example

```
old_files = project.files
project.some_operation_dealing_with_files
if old_files == project.files
   puts "not changed"
else
   puts "changed"
end
```

One of the problems on it is that on the first line, when you read `old_files  = project.files`, it is not clear where you want to get. I imagine that if I could eliminate that variable, the code would be better, but I don't know how to achieve this. I'm also, of course, open to suggestions.

**TLDR;** Is there a way to rewrite the code without the `old_file` variable?

Comment: This is hard, but you have to have some form of flag where you can toggle state. It's really hard otherwise because you don't want ambiguity in a method name and therefore you shouldnt do `if project.some_operation_dealing_with_files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the object aware if the files state changes and provide a query method to test it. Set the did_change status to false at the start of each method that could change the files state.

```
project.some_operation_with_files
if project.files_did_change?
  puts "Changed"
else
  puts "No change."
end
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however I can't be sure if the files were changed on that operation or somewhere else after being instantiated. Taking in account this limitation, could work. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Would returning a true/false status or throwing an exception work in your case? When the method returns false you should assume there were no changes in state of `project` anyway.

```
if project.some_operation_dealing_with_files
  puts "Changed"
else
  puts "Not Changed"
end
```

With an exception you can catch a specific type of error. Again if an error is thrown, `project` should be idempotent and the error should be handled gracefully.

```
begin
  project.some_operation_dealing_with_files
  puts "Changed"
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  puts "Not Changed. File not found."
  # Clean up and handle the error gracefully
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @limelights comments about the problem with returning true or false, and in a general way, in this point of the code I cold want to do something different than in other points depending if it changed or not. The exception workflow could do it nicely, but the fact of the files did not changed isn't an exception holds me back to think on it as a solution. I mean, exceptions are for exceptions, not for general control flow.

Comment: Ahh so even when files have not changed it can still mean the method was successful. In that case what about something like a `changed` method in the vein of activerecord? Assuming `project` is a composite, it can query each file for its state or somehow maintain the bookkeeping of the files it's responsible for.

Comment: Using an exception for flow-control in Ruby code is not recommended. See https://github.com/styleguide/ruby and https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @amesee `changed?` would be a good idea (that is exactly what @Fred proposed), but ironically I can't use in this very moment, because [of other issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816881/how-to-test-if-carrierwave-file-changed). Yet is a good idea generally.

Comment: @theTinMan To be fair I wasn't really suggesting the use of exception for flow control at all. My example clearly shows a scenario for a file not being found, which is an exceptional event. This is also why I asked if returning a true or false status would work.

Comment: Well, both @fotanus and I made the same comment, so obviously something led us to the same conclusion. There was no up/down vote in the balance from me, so it's more of an observation and recommendation to avoid that situation. Personally, if I can catch the situation in a conditional I'll do it. Exceptions are for exceptional situations.